# Need to retrieve the data from the function and write in the text file in macros excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have three functions, in macros excel. i am showing an example to understand

```
Sub main()
    Dim Obj As Object
    Dim File As Object
    Set Obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = Obj.createtextfile("c:\amix.txt"", True)
    A
    B
    C
End sub

Public Function A()
     file.writeline("ABC")
End Function



Public Function B()
     file.writeline("Def")
End Function



Public Function C()
     file.writeline("GHI")
End Function
```

Now i want to write all this function data into amix.txt notepad

And also if we write the two(Creating the Obj and Files) lines in every function, the text file is over riding for every function.

Now can you please suggest me with the code where i can get rid of my problem?

Comment: `Global Variables` should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, the error is you are not passing `File` to your functions. Try the following. It's tried and tested to work. Also, your directory has an extra `"` at the end. Not sure if just a typo on your part.

```
Sub main()
    Dim Obj As Object
    Dim File As Object
    Set Obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = Obj.CreateTextFile("c:\amix.txt", True)
    WriteA File
    WriteB File
    WriteC File
End Sub

Public Function WriteA(File As Object)
     File.writeline "ABC"
End Function

Public Function WriteB(File As Object)
     File.writeline "DEF"
End Function

Public Function WriteC(File As Object)
     File.writeline "GHI"
End Function
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you want to call a function inside another, just make sure the inner function exists first. There are no issues doing this. However, the practice is generally unorthodox at best. Same follows (tested and working):

```
Public Function WriteC(File As Object)
     'Calling WriteB inside WriteC as well.
     File.writeline "GHI"
     WriteB File
End Function
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code where i can call WriteB function from WriteC function...?

Public Function WriteB(File As Object)
     Dim word as string
     Word = "XYZ"
     File.writeline "DEF"
End Function

Public Function WriteC(File As Object)
     File.writeline "GHI"
End Function

I want to print the xyz in WriteC function. Can you please help me in this regard...?

Comment: Kindly post your code in your original question. It's difficult to read the codes in the comments area. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your text file object Global.  You also should use **Subs** rather than **Functions** .  For example:

```
    Dim Obj As Object
    Dim Ffile As Object
Sub main()
    Set Obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Ffile = Obj.createtextfile("C:\TestFolder\amix.txt", True)
    Call A
    Call B
    Call C
End Sub

Sub A()
     Ffile.writeline ("ABC")
End Sub

Sub B()
     Ffile.writeline ("Def")
End Sub

Sub C()
     Ffile.writeline ("GHI")
End Sub
```

Also, eventually you should perform

```
Ffile.Close
```

Comment: If we use more Subs, then those are visible while running from excel sheet. So in this case only one sub should be seen there.

Comment: @user3305322, you can use `Private Sub A() ...`. In that case only `Sub main()` would be visible from the ribbon